# Adding conditions to filter() dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add conditions in JavaScript `filter()` method dynamically.

I have the code below:

```
let condition = '';
let a = ['empEmail', 'employeeAction', 'transactionNo', 'deviceListName', 'projectName'];

if (this.selectedEmployeeAlias != undefined) {
  condition += '&& a => a.empEmail === this.selectedEmployeeAlias';
}
if (this.employeeStatusList != undefined) {
  condition += '&& a.employeeAction === this.employeeStatusList'
}
if (this.selectedTransactionNo != undefined) {
  condition += '&& a.transactionNo === this.selectedTransactionNo';
}
if (this.selectedDeviceList != undefined) {
  condition += ' && a.deviceListName == this.selectedDeviceList';
}
if (this.selectedProjectName != undefined) {
  condition += '&& a.projectName == this.selectedProjectName';
}

var finalCondition = condition.substring(2, condition.length);
var fArray = arrayDetails.filter(finalCondition);
```

The code is returning an error as:

> `finalCondition` is not a function.

Could you please let me know how can I add conditions to `filter()` dynamically.

Comment: Its because "finalCondition" is a string returned by "substring", the filter routine is expecting a function to be passed to it.  See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Comment: please add the sample data, you have and what `this` is pointing to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### `eval` to the Rescue!

While it's generally advised against, `eval` does exactly what you want here.

Just pass your `condition` variable to `eval` inside the `.filter` method and voila!

```
let condition='';
let a = ['empEmail', 'employeeAction', 'transactionNo', 'deviceListName', 'projectName'];

if (this.selectedEmployeeAlias != undefined) {                    
  condition += '&& a => a.empEmail === this.selectedEmployeeAlias';
}
if (this.employeeStatusList != undefined) {
  condition += '&& a.employeeAction === this.employeeStatusList'
}
if (this.selectedTransactionNo != undefined) {
  condition += '&& a.transactionNo === this.selectedTransactionNo';
}
if (this.selectedDeviceList != undefined) {
  condition += ' && a.deviceListName == this.selectedDeviceList';
}
if (this.selectedProjectName != undefined) {
  condition += '&& a.projectName == this.selectedProjectName';
}

var finalCondition=condition.substring(2, condition.length);
var fArray=arrayDetails.filter(stuff => eval(finalCondition));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take an array of functions with conditions. Then iterate with `every`.

```
var conditions = [];

if (this.selectedEmployeeAlias !== undefined) {
    conditions.push(a => a.empEmail === this.selectedEmployeeAlias);
}
if (this.employeeStatusList !== undefined) {
    conditions.push(a => a.employeeAction === this.employeeStatusList);
}
if (this.selectedTransactionNo !== undefined) {
    conditions.push(a => a.transactionNo === this.selectedTransactionNo);
}
if (this.selectedDeviceList !== undefined) {
    conditions.push(a => a.deviceListName == this.selectedDeviceList);
}
if (this.selectedProjectName !== undefined) {
    conditions.push(a => a.projectName == this.selectedProjectName);
}

var fArray = arrayDetails.filter(o => conditions.every(c => c(o)));
```

Comment: Omitting `!= undefined` seems dangerous. What if its `0` or `false` or ...

Comment: right, the properties could contains numbers and empty strings, or what ever falsy values.

Answer (score 0):

As you got the nakes of the keys, just loop over them and check for undefineds:

```
const keys = ['empEmail', 'employeeAction', 'transactionNo', 'deviceListName', 'projectName'];

const result = arrayDetails.filter(el => {
   for(const key of keys) {
     if(this[key] === undefined) continue;
     if(this[key] !== el[key]) return false;
   }
   return true;
});
```